# Cross compiling Direct3D on Linux with mingw

Tags: c++, directx, mingw, cross-compiling, mingw32

How to configure mingw32 to cross-compile Direct3D Apps for Windows? Is there any possibility? I have actually succeeded compiling code from this tutorial: http://www.directxtutorial.com/Tutorial9/B-Direct3DBasics/dx9B4.aspx - using Code::Blocks on Kubuntu with i586-mingw32msvc-g++. I needed to add `#define UNICODE` and remove the `#pragma ...` parts to do this, and I used header files from /usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include and libs also from mingw package.

However I cannot compile code from this tutorial: http://www.directxtutorial.com/Tutorial9/B-Direct3DBasics/dx9B5.aspx

Mingw doesn't have `d3dx9.h` file. So I've installed `wine1.2-dev` package with wine versions of Windows-related header files, but now I have errors:

With `#define UNICODE`:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in d3d ---------------

i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -Wall  -g    -I/usr/include/wine/windows  -c /home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp: In function ‘int WinMain(HINSTANCE__*, HINSTANCE__*, CHAR*, int)’:
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:50: error: invalid conversion from ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘const WCHAR*’
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:56: error: invalid conversion from ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘const WCHAR*’
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:56: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘HWND__* CreateWindowExW(DWORD, const WCHAR*, const WCHAR*, DWORD, INT, INT, INT, INT, HWND__*, HMENU__*, HINSTANCE__*, void*)’
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:56: error: invalid conversion from ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘const WCHAR*’
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:56: error:   initializing argument 3 of ‘HWND__* CreateWindowExW(DWORD, const WCHAR*, const WCHAR*, DWORD, INT, INT, INT, INT, HWND__*, HMENU__*, HINSTANCE__*, void*)’
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp: In function ‘void render_frame()’:
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:158: warning: taking address of temporary
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:159: warning: taking address of temporary
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:160: warning: taking address of temporary
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
5 errors, 3 warnings
```

And without the `#define`:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in d3d ---------------

i586-mingw32msvc-g++ -Wall  -g    -I/usr/include/wine/windows  -c /home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp: In function ‘int WinMain(HINSTANCE__*, HINSTANCE__*, CHAR*, int)’:
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:50: error: cannot convert ‘const wchar_t [12]’ to ‘const CHAR*’ in assignment
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:56: error: cannot convert ‘const wchar_t*’ to ‘const CHAR*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘HWND__* CreateWindowExA(DWORD, const CHAR*, const CHAR*, DWORD, INT, INT, INT, INT, HWND__*, HMENU__*, HINSTANCE__*, void*)’
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp: In function ‘void render_frame()’:
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:158: warning: taking address of temporary
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:159: warning: taking address of temporary
/home/silmeth/programowanie/codeblocks/d3d/main.cpp:160: warning: taking address of temporary
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
2 errors, 3 warnings
```

Here is the whole code I'm trying to compile:

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header file
#define UNICODE //tried to comment and uncomment this
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

// define the screen resolution
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// include the Direct3D Library files
//#pragma comment (lib, "d3d9.lib")
//#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx9.lib")

// global declarations
LPDIRECT3D9 d3d;    // the pointer to our Direct3D interface
LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev;    // the pointer to the device class
LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 v_buffer = NULL;    // the pointer to the vertex buffer

// function prototypes
void initD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void render_frame(void);    // renders a single frame
void cleanD3D(void);    // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void init_graphics(void);    // 3D declarations

struct CUSTOMVERTEX {FLOAT X, Y, Z; DWORD COLOR;};
#define CUSTOMFVF (D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE)

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL, L"WindowClass", L"Our Direct3D Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                          NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    initD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }

        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;

        render_frame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    cleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void initD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

    D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;

    ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
    d3dpp.Windowed = TRUE;
    d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
    d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = hWnd;
    d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8;
    d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = SCREEN_HEIGHT;

    // create a device class using this information and the info from the d3dpp stuct
    d3d->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
                      D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
                      hWnd,
                      D3DCREATE_SOFTWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
                      &d3dpp,
                      &d3ddev);

    init_graphics();    // call the function to initialize the triangle

    d3ddev->SetRenderState(D3DRS_LIGHTING, FALSE);    // turn off the 3D lighting
}


// this is the function used to render a single frame
void render_frame(void)
{
    d3ddev->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 0), 1.0f, 0);

    d3ddev->BeginScene();

    // select which vertex format we are using
    d3ddev->SetFVF(CUSTOMFVF);

    // SET UP THE PIPELINE

    D3DXMATRIX matRotateY;    // a matrix to store the rotation information

    static float index = 0.0f; index+=0.05f;    // an ever-increasing float value

    // build a matrix to rotate the model based on the increasing float value
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRotateY, index);

    // tell Direct3D about our matrix
    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD, &matRotateY);

    D3DXMATRIX matView;    // the view transform matrix

    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&matView,
                       &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f),    // the camera position
                       &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),    // the look-at position
                       &D3DXVECTOR3 (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));    // the up direction

    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_VIEW, &matView);    // set the view transform to matView

    D3DXMATRIX matProjection;     // the projection transform matrix

    D3DXMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(&matProjection,
                               D3DXToRadian(45),    // the horizontal field of view
                               (FLOAT)SCREEN_WIDTH / (FLOAT)SCREEN_HEIGHT, // aspect ratio
                               1.0f,    // the near view-plane
                               100.0f);    // the far view-plane

    d3ddev->SetTransform(D3DTS_PROJECTION, &matProjection);    // set the projection

    // select the vertex buffer to display
    d3ddev->SetStreamSource(0, v_buffer, 0, sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX));

    // copy the vertex buffer to the back buffer
    d3ddev->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLELIST, 0, 1);

    d3ddev->EndScene();

    d3ddev->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void cleanD3D(void)
{
    v_buffer->Release();    // close and release the vertex buffer
    d3ddev->Release();    // close and release the 3D device
    d3d->Release();    // close and release Direct3D
}


// this is the function that puts the 3D models into video RAM
void init_graphics(void)
{
    // create the vertices using the CUSTOMVERTEX struct
    CUSTOMVERTEX vertices[] =
    {
        { 3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255), },
        { 0.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0), },
        { -3.0f, -3.0f, 0.0f, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0), },
    };

    // create a vertex buffer interface called v_buffer
    d3ddev->CreateVertexBuffer(3*sizeof(CUSTOMVERTEX),
                               0,
                               CUSTOMFVF,
                               D3DPOOL_MANAGED,
                               &v_buffer,
                               NULL);

    VOID* pVoid;    // a void pointer

    // lock v_buffer and load the vertices into it
    v_buffer->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    v_buffer->Unlock();
}
```

Do I have to install through wine MS DirectX SDK? Change something with the code? I'm DirectX- and Windows-related things noob but I just want to cross-compile some simple examples of D3D and check if this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok! I've finally succeeded!

Unfortunately, I needed to download Microsoft DirectX SDK (April 2007) (I couldn't install newer ones with wine).

Then I had to install MinGW using wine and also install mingw-utils 0.3 (I had to obtain reimp.exe file).

Then I set up PATH in wine's register to `C:\windows;C:\windows\system;C:\MinGW\bin`

Then I made `wine reimp.exe "C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (April 2007)/Lib/x86/d3dx9.lib"`. This command generated `d3dx9_33.a` file, I've changed it to `d3dx9.a` and put it in `/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/lib/`.

I have also copied all lacking header files from DirectX SDK to `/usr/i586-mingw32msvc/include`.

And then... I compiled the program, linking it to libd3d9.a and libd3dx9.a, and it compiled, linked, and it WORKS!

So the good news is: one can compile Windows DirectX programs under Linux using Linux version of MinGW.

The bad news: one need to install a few MinGW utilities and whole MS DX SDK using wine.

**EDIT**

And one more thing: I needed to make all WCHAR*-related castings manually - mingw shouts with errors if it isn't done. Goz was helpful here.

Answer (score 2):

If you change your strings to

```
(const WCHAR*)L"blah blah"
```

Then it should compile its not ideal but it seems that wchar_t and WCHAR are not compatible under mingw.  I'm not entirely sure why it doesn't compile though as windows.h defines WCHAR as a typedef of wchar_t ...

Comment: Ok, that works. Still there is lacking libd3dx9.a file (I need to link with it). I solved it, however, by using mingw dlltool by using wine's d3dx9_36.dll and libd3dx9.def... Heh, it would be easier to just install MS DirectX SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You can also you the plain mingw crosscompiler in for instance Debian or Ubuntu, and the code for DirectX only using LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress(). (But the tutorials on DirectX can't be used as-is then.)