# g++ windows using DirectX?

Tags: windows, cross-platform, directx, g++

Is it possible to compile code using g++ on Windows and to use DirectX?  Are there major speed differences from using the Visual Studio compiler?  Since DirectX is already a compiled library I assume there's no difference.  Does any kind of licensing prevent this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MinGW-32 will work fine, either on Windows or cross-compiling from Linux.

[Cross compiling Direct3D on Linux with mingw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813115/cross-compiling-direct3d-on-linux-with-mingw)

Note that unfortunately MSVC still produces faster code, you will need to test to gauge how much of a difference though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mingw (a Windows port of gcc/g++) with DirectX.

http://mingw-starter.blogspot.com/2008/02/mingw-directx.html